# Synchronized Data Extension marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

**BackGround**

- Marketing cloud and sales cloud connected
- In contact i have 141049 records which are already sync
- I created new record on contact object
- Go back to sync and refresh it .

**Question**

1. Why my record not sync ? Its still showing me 141049 record which is totally wrong
2. When we are creating record in sales cloud object it is necessary that we need to refresh the data source ?
3. I want automatically sync relationship .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the synchronised objects in order to keep them in sync and then adjust the polling time. The polling time dictates how often data will be refreshed between the two systems. Once this is set up, it will automatically sync.

A couple of ‘got ya’s’

1. The sync is not in real time: you can reduce the polling to as little as 15 mins
2. Dependencies: if your object is a child of other objects, then you would have to sync the parent objects first